# Springfox swagger JSON?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

In a springboot app context, i'm looking for the .json output of swagger.

Seems that in the docs, the /v2/api-docs is available, but there's nothing within this url in my project.

The UI swagger is available under /swagger-ui.html,
where can I find the json output ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no physical json file/resource. It is generated at run-time and served up from memory.

Secondly the swagger-ui.html and all the javascript/css/images resources are served up from the [springfox-swagger-ui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.6.0) library which is packaged up as a [web-jars](http://www.webjars.org).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. You will have to provide the group name.

```
http://<host>:<port>/v2/api-docs?group=<group-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have json endpoint out of the box. As I know, you have to build Docket for for every endpoint. Here is an example:

```
                Docket endpointDocket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                        .groupName("yourGroupName")
                        .select()
                        .paths(regex("yourEndpointUrl"))
                        .build();
```

You have to register it in app context. Then you will have url (as mentioned by mephis-slayer):

```
http://<host>:<port>/v2/api-docs?group=yourGroupName
```